# How to execute php file directly in browser

Tags: php

I have Project called Project2 in the Workspace( namely WorkSpace), which is inside the folder `htdocs`.

I have installed XAMPP in my machine.
so the path of the project is `C:\xampp\htdocs\WorkSpace\Project2`

Now i want to execute the file called `Add.php`, which is in the Project2 folder.
How can I execute the Add.php file in the browser directly.

Please spend few seconds for my query ........

Comment: http://localhost/WorkSpace/Project2/Add.php

Comment: First, write a browser plugin that encapsulates the PHP compiler and Zend engine...

Comment: Have you tried http://127.0.0.1/WorkSpace/Project2/Add.php  ?

Comment: Upon the browsers request, the PHP is executed by the server and the resulting html is sent to the browser. The server in this case runs on your localhost.

Comment: all suggestions work here but make sure that your webserver `apache` is running

Comment: I have tried this and getting error as <br/> Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 404
localhost
3/24/2011 5:06:33 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: What does C:\xampp\htdocs\WorkSpace\Project2 tell you? and C:\xampp\htdocs\WorkSpace ?

Comment: its the path where i have kept my project..

Comment: Sorry I meant  
What does http://localhost/WorkSpace/Project2 tell you? and  http://localhost/WorkSpace ?

Comment: Its giving the error as................   Object Not Found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 404    localhost
3/24/2011 5:01:33 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: Take a look at felixsigl comment

Answer (score 3):

visit http://localhost/WorkSpace/Project2/Add.php in your browser

Apache must be up an running - you can start Apache with XAMPP Control Panel

Comment: I tried this but i am getting the Error saying                                     Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 

Error 404
localhost
3/24/2011 5:01:33 PM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

Comment: @Gnanendra hit `localhost` and see what you get

Comment: After enter the localhost.. I am getting  

Welcome to XAMPP for Windows! msg and XAMPP window

Comment: did you define any rewrite rules for example in a .htaccess file?